# A python code to summarize data of one column based on ordered value of another column

Tags: python

I am dealing with a data where I have two columns, lets say "time" & "activity".
The time data is a python datetime value in ascending order whereas the activity takes numeric value starting from 0 till 5.
The catch about the activity variable is that it has repeated ordered values from 0 to 5 & back to 0 again.
For e.g. 0,0,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,4,4,3,2,1,1,0,0.

The dataset(a snippet of 17 observations) looks like:

time:     t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14,t15,t16,t17
activity: 0,0,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,4,4,3,2,1,1,0,0

Now, my question is :  HOW DO I CALCULATE THE TIME TAKEN FOR THE ACTIVITY TO REACH FROM 0 TO 5 FOLLOWED BY 5 TO 0. I WANT TO DO IT IN PYTHON.

I explored certain areas but not fruitful enough to be shared.

The result I am looking for would typically create 2 objects like:
1. timefrom0to5= (t8-t1) secs
2. timefrom5to0= (t17-t9) secs

Any help would be highly appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any ideas of your own?  Have you written any code at all yet?  This is a site for asking specific questions about programming, not a place to say "how do I solve this problem?", or "please write this code for me".  You need to get started yourself and get to a place that shows you've at least thought about the problem yourself.  Then you can come back here for specific help.  Have you written Python code before?

Comment: So you can assume what...that there will be two 5s in the sequence, they will be the largest values, and you want to split the times between the two of them?  Or does your code need to figure what the highest numbers are, and how many of them there are?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.